# How to melt two data frames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames:

```
In [14]: rep1
Out[14]: 
   x  y  z
A  1  2  3
B  4  5  6
C  1  1  2

In [15]: rep2
Out[15]: 
   x  y  z
A  7  3  4
B  3  3  3
```

created with this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
rep1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6]),('C',[1,1,2])], orient='index', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
rep2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [7, 3, 4]), ('B', [3, 3, 3])], orient='index', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

What I want to do then is to mesh `rep1` and `rep2` so that it results something like this:

```
gene rep1 rep2 type
A     1    7    x
B     4    3    x
A     2    3    y
B     5    3    y
A     3    4    z
B     6    3    z
```

row C is skipped because it is not shared by `rep1` and `rep2`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
df =pd.concat([rep1.stack(),rep2.stack()],axis=1).reset_index().dropna()
df.columns =['GENE','TYPE','REP1','REP2']
df.sort(columns=['TYPE','GENE'], inplace=True)
```

Concatenate the stacked data frames on `axis =1`. Resetting the index gets you back the gene and type columns. `dropna` takes care of the nulls produced for gene c. Add the correct column names etc.

returns:

```
   GENE TYPE REP1 REP2
0   A   x   1   7
3   B   x   4   3
1   A   y   2   3
4   B   y   5   3
2   A   z   3   4
5   B   z   6   3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> c1 = rep1.values.T.flatten()
>>> c2 = rep2.values.T.flatten()
>>> c3 = np.vstack((rep1.columns.values, rep2.columns.values)).T.flatten()
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((c1,c2,c3)).T)
   0  1  2
0  1  7  x
1  4  3  x
2  2  3  y
3  5  3  y
4  3  4  z
5  6  3  z
```

Edit: When I was answering this, the question did not have row C at all.  Now things are more complicated, but I'll leave this here anyway.